# Vipre antivirus on virtualized server 2012

Tags: anti-virus, symantec

Can anyone confirm that Vipre ('VIPRE Antivirus Business') runs ok in a 2012 server environment?

This is only for a simple single server solution, no need for managing workstations etc.  Feedback about Vipre from elsewhere seems to be good but not much info about using this on a virtualized Server 2012.

Existing 2003 server uses Symantec but I would like to find something better for the new 2012 server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [system requirements](http://www.threattracksecurity.com/business-antivirus/vipre-antivirus-business/requirements.aspx) page for the product show that it supports Windows Server 2012:

> **VIPRE Agent (Windows)** 
>   Operating systems
>
> - Windows 8 (32- & 64-bit)
> - Windows 7 (32- & 64-bit)
> - Windows Vista, Vista SP1+(32- & 64-bit)
> - Windows XP Professional SP2+ (32- & 64-bit)
> - Windows Server 2012
> - Windows Small Business Server 2011, 2008 and 2003
> - Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 (excluding Server 2008 Core)
> - Windows Server 2003 SP1+ (32 & 64-bit)
> - Windows 2000 Server with SP4 RU1 or later (supports legacy 5.0 agents for upgrade only)
> - Windows 2000 Professional with SP4 RU1 or later (supports legacy 5.0 agents for upgrade only)
> - Windows Embedded for Point of Service (WEPOS) platforms

Please take the 5 minutes to check the obvious places first and/or work through the actual software vendor first. As far as if it runs well, I think that's a very open ended question and can't really be answered easily here. What works for one person doesn't always behave the same way for other people.

Comment: Thanks Rex but I had seen that.  What I was hoping for was to find out if anyone is actually using Vipre in a production environment.  On one hand it seems to be a good product but it has only a small slice of the market which makes me worry about relying on it for a server.